# MacBook doesn't turn on after SSD switch

Tags: keyboard, ssd, sleep-wake

I have Mid 2012 MacBook Air. I decided to clean it from dust, but I totally forgot to shut it down instead put it into sleep mode. I removed the SSD while it was asleep, I think this is the issue.

Now it turns on in like 40 minutes.

[image]

Coolers are working on max speed, and after loading bar finishing, I have this:

[image]

It's said to connect Apple mouse, but I cannot connect it either it's ignoring it.

While attempting to boot as shown in the screenshot, nothing works - keyboard, mouse, trackpad, USB.

I googled and I found many solutions, but nothing helps me since keyboard and trackpad/USB mouse are totally not working. Like, reset RAM cache, etc. E.g. one of the solutions was to hold <kbd>Command</kbd> +  <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> keys after power on.

I really want to make it work again. Any clue on how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried resetting the SMC? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295

Comment: Try plugging in an external keyboard.

Comment: @user136952 yes, i tried

Comment: @historystamp it doens't work since usb are not working as i get. Same with mouse - it doesn't work

Comment: pull out the hard drive and reset the smc.

Comment: @user136952 do you mean to reset SMC without hard drive, and then insert it?

Comment: Yea reset the SMC without the hard drive in. Let it boot to the folder and question mark. Power it down. Attach the hard drive. Boot again.normally.